# Testing AngularJS Service with Jasmine throw an error with parsed.protocol

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test some services that receive some modifications. Some of them are using $http service, and only one of them is populating an unknown - and a not understandable - issue.

Let me expose.

```
it('must reject the promise with an explanation if the required path is not found', function() {
   $httpBackend.whenGET('http://localhost/testok').respond(function () {
        return [200, mockedRemoteResponse, {}];
   });

   var promise = apiDataExtractor.extractRemoteData('ok', 'toto');

   $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

Running this code throught Jasmine, we got this:
[image: Jasmine parsed.protocol issue]

I do not have ANY idea of what appends. I try to change injection order, try to erase and rewrite my test, there is something here I'm missing.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is probably due to a call to $http.get with undefined as the url (you might have forgotten to provide parameters to $http.get() inside apiDataExtractor.extractRemoteData?)

Try debugging your code and see what are the parameters you are giving the $http.get method.

Comment: All injections are mocked, so there is no additionnal call.. Except maybe.. Tomorrow at work ;)